# Stream audio from Windows application over WebRTC connection

Tags: webrtc, audio-streaming

I'm trying to stream audio from a specific Windows process over a WebRTC P2P connection.

I've found a Windows API that allows you to extract the audio from a specific Windows
process through a callback:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/ApplicationLoopback

I'm not an expert on WebRTC, but the P2P connection between 2 clients have been establised.

From what I can tell the next step is to create an audio source that inherits from `webrtc::LocalAudioSource` and from that create an `AudioTrack()` and then `AddTrack()` to the peer connection.
But after that I'm not sure how to pipe the audio from the Windows API callback into the audio track?

```
// Implement AudioSourceInterface
class MyAudioSource : public webrtc::LocalAudioSource {
public:
    MyAudioSource() {}
    ~MyAudioSource() override {}
};

int main() {
    // Initialize PeerConnectionFactory
    rtc::InitializeSSL();
    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::PeerConnectionFactoryInterface> peer_factory =
            webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory();

    // Create AudioSource
    rtc::scoped_refptr<MyAudioSource> audio_source(new rtc::RefCountedObject<MyAudioSource>());

    // Create AudioTrack
    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioTrackInterface> audio_track =
            peer_factory->CreateAudioTrack("audio_track_id", audio_source);

    // Create PeerConnection
    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::PeerConnectionInterface> peer_connection =
            peer_factory->CreatePeerConnection(...);

    // Add audio track to PeerConnection
    peer_connection->AddTrack(audio_track, {});
return 0;
}
```

I tried the code posted above. The code builds and runs, but I don't know how to pipe audio into the audio track.